# format statement in Fortran with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Hi this is code given in Chapman's book Fortran 95-2003 for scientists and engineers(3ed) on page 195

```
WRITE (*,100) index, time, depth, amplitude, phase

100 FORMAT('1',t20,'results for the test number  ',i3,///,&
      1x,'time      = ',f7.0/, &
      1x,'depth     = ',f7.1,' meters',/, &
      1x,'amplitude = ',f8.2/ &,
      1x,'phase     = ',f7.1)
```

To run it, I completed rest of the statements

```
program test
implicit none

INTEGER :: index = 10
real:: time=300.0,depth=330.0,amplitude=850.65,phase=30.0
WRITE (*,100) index, time, depth, amplitude, phase

100 FORMAT('1',t20,'results for the test number  ',i3,///,&
      1x,'time      = ',f7.0/, &
      1x,'depth     = ',f7.1,' meters',/, &
      1x,'amplitude = ',f8.2/ &,
      1x,'phase     = ',f7.1)

end program test
```

When i compile it with gfortran, I get following errors..

```
test.f90:12.31:

      1x,'amplitude = ',f8.2/ &,
                               1
Error: Unexpected element '&' in format string at (1)
test.f90:13.8:

      1x,'phase     = ',f7.1)
        1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
test.f90:13.9:

      1x,'phase     = ',f7.1)
         1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
test.f90:7.12:

WRITE (*,100) index, time, depth, amplitude, phase
            1
Error: FORMAT label 100 at (1) not defined
```

whats happening here ? I have seen another thread here at stackoverflow, where the question was about the control characters in fortran. Chapman discusses it in his book without mentioning that the feature of control characters has been deleted in Fortran 2003. So I am wondering if this is similar old thing not recognized by gfortran ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a comma after the ampersand on the line of the format specification that has the 'ampersand = ' literal.  To act as a continuation character in a non-character context the ampersand must be the last non-blank, non-comment character on the line.

The comma should probably be before the ampersand.

(Because the ampersand is not treated as a continuation character, the compiler thinks it is part of the format specification - hence the first error.  The next line is then taken to start a new statement - hence the subsequent errors.)

Comment: bingo!!!!!! So Chapman made a mistake here. I checked his errata file.But they don't cover this. It seems I am seeing lot of typos in this book. I probably will switch to something else. By browsing few threads here I found http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/docs/course-notes/unix-courses/Fortran